# UICollectionView cell contentView completely blank

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am facing one issue. And I think it might be a weird one. I am using UICollectionViewController and configure it something like this

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }
             flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
             flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height: 60)
             flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(
                top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10
             ) 

        collectionView.register(DemoTakesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DemoTakesCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return 2
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DemoTakesCollectionViewCell.identifier,
                                                        for: indexPath) as? DemoTakesCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError("UICollectionView must be downcasted to CollectionViewCell")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

I did also register a cell for `UICollectionView`, but its content not showing up somehow. In View Hierarchy, Cell is there but not it's content. What could be a problem here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You designed your cell as a Storyboard Prototype? If so, remove the `collectionView.register(DemoTakesCollectionViewCell.self ...` line from `viewDidLoad()` and see if your cell content shows up.

Comment: @DonMag It's xib, so I have to register it with collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... you left out an important piece of information in your question:

***"It's xib"***

So this line:

```
collectionView.register(DemoTakesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DemoTakesCollectionViewCell.identifier)
```

registers the **class** -- but the class isn't adding any UI elements.

You need to register the **nib**:

```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "DemoTakesCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DemoTakesCollectionViewCell.identifier)
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: Ahh. Right. I too missed out on that thing. smh :)